# "a view to" vs. "a view of" vs. "a view on"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions

What is the difference, if any, between the meaning of "a view to" and "a view of"?

Example:

> a new view of environmentalism

vs.

> a new view to environmentalism

vs.

> A new view on Environmentalism

Both can be found with more or less frequency on the web, and the same on [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20view%20to%2Ca%20view%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20view%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20view%20of%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: The fact that they are both used is unrelated to using them in your sentence. The first is the sentence you want, a new way of seeing biology. Here's where 'view to' works: "With a view to (or towards) feeding his family, he stocked his kitchen with staples and fresh produce." Prepositions are very idiomatic, the technical term for Don't Ask Why.

Comment: What @YosefBaskin said.

Comment: @YosefBaskin So, "a new view to ..." is absurd?

Comment: @Drew What about something like "adding a new view (meaning adding a new perspective) to environmentalism"?

Comment: What about it?...

Comment: @Drew is it meaningful?

Comment: It could be. What do you want it to mean? And what does it have to do with your actual question. The question is becoming less and less clear.

Comment: *Adding to* environmentalism is fine. So *adding (a new view) to* it is fine, too, since we no longer have 'a new view to' meaning what it does on its own. Nobody called a misuse of 'view to' absurd. We are here to help each other.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?num=20&lr=lang_en&biw=1298&bih=603&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en%2Cbkv%3Ap&tbm=bks&ei=VpbkW8mJO4zhvgSOsL6QCQ&q=%22a+new+view+on%22&oq=%22a+new+view+on%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...20636.22185.0.22857.4.4.0.0.0.0.153.483.1j3.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0._icKu3bNyjA

Answer (score 2):

They can't both be found in the same context, though, and if they could then still, there are huge difference between *A* and *A new*.

*A view of…* describes a perspective on… *A new view of…* makes the perspective fresh.

*A view to…* describes a tendency towards… *A new view to…* makes the phrase wholly unworkable.

Comment: What about "with a new view to ..." ? Is it meaningless ?

Comment: Yes, Sasan, *with a new view to…* is meaningless.

It just might be grammatically acceptable but it would still be strongly unidiomatic.

Comment: What about something like "adding a new view (meaning adding a new perspective) to environmentalism"?

Comment: You could say that but it wouldn't mean anything such as we've been discussing; it wouldn’t, for instance, mean *adding a new view (perspective) of environmentalism.*

Rather it would mean *including within the definition of environmentalism a new view.*


Does the difference make sense?